# Create a new object with a Checkbox using Office Toolkit 4

Tags: force.com

I'm trying to create a new object inside a Console C# App using Framework 3.5, Visual Studio 2010 and Office Toolkit 4.

This object has a Checkbox field, with false as its default value.

After populating the object, the Create method crashes without further details, it seems like the COM component masks the error.

Here's what i have.

```
//Create object
SObject4 obj = sForceSession4.CreateObject("Test__c");

//Populate it
obj.Item("Checkbox__c").Value = false;
obj.Item("Name").Value = "uniquevalue";

//Crash!
obj.Create();
```

I'm just getting an E_FAIL undefined HRESULT as an exception after invoking Create.

Other fields with different data types work ok receiving their values as strings.

Thanks in advance.